# application to receive the request c#

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

Currently I have created a method in webapi to send a request by uploading the x509 certificate.

Now i need to write and application receive this request sent by the api and validate the certificate, could you please let me know how this must be done? I'm preety new to this.

Comment: Are you looking to write a web service that this code would call, i.e. the URL of which is what would be passed in via the `requestUri` parameter?

Comment: As i said i completely new to this, just need a application which will listen to the request and receive it. If Webservice does that then please let me know how this must be done?

Answer (score 1):

You will likely want to use a web service as your receiver. It would impractical to explain how to create a web service as there are a tremendous amount of examples readily available by doing a quick search on google for `C# Web Service` or `C# RESTful Web Service example`.

Here are a couple of results to get you started:

- [HOW TO: Write a Simple Web Service by Using Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308359)
- [Restful webservices in C#](http://www.csharpstar.com/restful-webservices-in-csharp/)

If you work through one or two example projects and you run into a problem that you can't figure out, come back and post a new question. As it is, this question is a bit vague, so this will probably be about as specific of an answer as you're going to get.